# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\ln{n})^2+n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following series converge or diverge $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\ln{n})^2+n}$$
I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln{n})^2}$ diverges.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\ln{n})^2}$ dominates the series in question, and converges. What comparison can I use to understand this?

Comment: Useful keyword: it's a [Bertrand series](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html).

Comment: Show that the convergence of your series is implied by the convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{n(\ln n)^2}$. Then use integral test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{1}{n\log^2(n)+n}\le \frac{1}{n\log^2(n)}$$

and

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x\log^2(x)}\,dx=\frac{1}{\log(2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

[The Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) gives that your series is convergent iff
$$ \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{1+m^2}=\frac{1+\pi\coth \pi}{2} $$
is convergent.